# how to move the scanner back

Tags: java, string

I have a mission. I have read a text and save each set of three words into a string variable. The problem is that after the progress of three words, the scanner should be placed one step ahead.

For example,

- In row 2 of the print should be typed "adventure of the".
- In row 3 - "of the bruce-partington"

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing A) because you have not provided code for others to copy/paste and reproduce the issue B) you have not showed in your question how your input looks like (sample input) and what output you are getting, how the output should look like. The above screenshot is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the scanner back. Simply **save the content of the last two read words in a String**. When you read the next word, push the index forward. Something like this (**pseudo code!**):

```
String firstWord, secondWord, lastWord;

//You need to check if Scanner.hasNext()
firstWord = Scanner.next();
secondWord = Scanner.next();
lastWord = Scanner.next();

sysout.print (firstWord, secondWord, lastWord);

while (Scanner.hasNext() ) {
   //save the two words for the next output
   firstWord = secondWord;
   secondWord = lastWord;
   lastWord = Scanner.next();

   //print the read lines with the old ones first
   sysout.print (firstWord, secondWord, lastWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this method. Maybe this will help!

```
public static void func(){
    String line="the adventure of the bruce-partington in the third week of november , in the year";
    Scanner linescanner=new Scanner(line);
    String newString="";
    Scanner linescannerTWO;
    if(linescanner.hasNext()){
        String tock=linescanner.next();
        String tock2=linescanner.next();
        String tock3=linescanner.next();
        newString=(tock+" "+tock2+" "+tock3);
        System.out.println(newString);

    }
    while(linescanner.hasNext()){
        linescannerTWO=new Scanner(newString);
        String tock=linescanner.next();
        linescannerTWO.next();
        String tock3=linescannerTWO.next();
        String tock4=linescannerTWO.next();
        newString=(tock3+" "+tock4+" "+tock);
        System.out.println(newString);

    }

}
```